# Include JQuery Fade Out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a fade in on a certain DIV that works well, but I'm looking to create a fade out on that same DIV as well. I've tried a few different options, but they kill the functionality or just don't work. I'll post them below. My current script that works with the fade in is here in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6oy1ry4f/5/

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var height = $(window).height();
    $('.fadeinblock').css({
        'opacity': ((height - scrollTop) / height)
    });
});
```

And a full fade in/fade out with no luck:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   if($(window).scrollTop()<20){
         $('.fadeinblock').stop(true,true).fadeIn("slow");
   } else {
         $('.fadeinblock').stop(true,true).fadeOut("slow");
   }
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Rory My fiddle has JQuery included: https://jsfiddle.net/6oy1ry4f/5/. Just noticed that you may need to adjust your screen size so that you can scroll in the output section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try jquery's `.fadeToggle()`.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  $('.fadeinblock').fadeToggle('slow', 'linear'); // it takes a bunch of other options if you don't like those.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For the transition you can use css transition.

About the condition of fadeIn/Out you can use this:

```js
$('.one').css({
  opacity: $(window).scrollTop() > 20 ? 100 : 0
});
```

And a live example:

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
  $('.one').css({
    opacity: $(window).scrollTop() > 20 ? 100 : 0
  });
});
```

```css
.one {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slide2">
  <div class="content">
    <h2>Header</h2>
    <div class="quotes_container">
      <div class="fadeinblock">
        <div class="one">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In pretium non enim et ornare. Duis volutpat lacus dui, sed blandit dui hendrerit vel. Fusce sodales augue sed ornare venenatis. Cras sit amet neque placerat, sagittis turpis ac, interdum
            sem. Maecenas scelerisque, eros et congue dapibus, enim nisl dapibus felis, a fringilla mi turpis ut turpis. Nulla tincidunt, nulla a interdum dictum, nulla magna ultricies sem, vel accumsan arcu enim vitae augue. Integer lobortis nunc in
            massa commodo imperdiet. Aliquam dignissim mauris a tortor sollicitudin, et rhoncus purus laoreet. Maecenas convallis velit justo, eget semper eros volutpat a.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In pretium non enim et ornare. Duis volutpat lacus dui, sed blandit dui hendrerit vel. Fusce sodales augue sed ornare venenatis. Cras sit amet neque placerat, sagittis turpis ac, interdum
            sem. Maecenas scelerisque, eros et congue dapibus, enim nisl dapibus felis, a fringilla mi turpis ut turpis. Nulla tincidunt, nulla a interdum dictum, nulla magna ultricies sem, vel accumsan arcu enim vitae augue. Integer lobortis nunc in
            massa commodo imperdiet. Aliquam dignissim mauris a tortor sollicitudin, et rhoncus purus laoreet. Maecenas convallis velit justo, eget semper eros volutpat a.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In pretium non enim et ornare. Duis volutpat lacus dui, sed blandit dui hendrerit vel. Fusce sodales augue sed ornare venenatis. Cras sit amet neque placerat, sagittis turpis ac, interdum
            sem. Maecenas scelerisque, eros et congue dapibus, enim nisl dapibus felis, a fringilla mi turpis ut turpis. Nulla tincidunt, nulla a interdum dictum, nulla magna ultricies sem, vel accumsan arcu enim vitae augue. Integer lobortis nunc in
            massa commodo imperdiet. Aliquam dignissim mauris a tortor sollicitudin, et rhoncus purus laoreet. Maecenas convallis velit justo, eget semper eros volutpat a.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In pretium non enim et ornare. Duis volutpat lacus dui, sed blandit dui hendrerit vel. Fusce sodales augue sed ornare venenatis. Cras sit amet neque placerat, sagittis turpis ac, interdum
            sem. Maecenas scelerisque, eros et congue dapibus, enim nisl dapibus felis, a fringilla mi turpis ut turpis. Nulla tincidunt, nulla a interdum dictum, nulla magna ultricies sem, vel accumsan arcu enim vitae augue. Integer lobortis nunc in
            massa commodo imperdiet. Aliquam dignissim mauris a tortor sollicitudin, et rhoncus purus laoreet. Maecenas convallis velit justo, eget semper eros volutpat a.</p>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In pretium non enim et ornare. Duis volutpat lacus dui, sed blandit dui hendrerit vel. Fusce sodales augue sed ornare venenatis. Cras sit amet neque placerat, sagittis turpis ac, interdum sem. Maecenas
            scelerisque, eros et congue dapibus, enim nisl dapibus felis, a fringilla mi turpis ut turpis. Nulla tincidunt, nulla a interdum dictum, nulla magna ultricies sem, vel accumsan arcu enim vitae augue. Integer lobortis nunc in massa commodo
            imperdiet. Aliquam dignissim mauris a tortor sollicitudin, et rhoncus purus laoreet. Maecenas convallis velit justo, eget semper eros volutpat a.
          </p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't assign the "jumpToEnd" parameter for "stop". It seems to be causing transition issues.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var fade = $(".fadeinblock");

    fade.stop(true);

    if($(window).scrollTop() < 20) {
        fade.fadeIn("slow");
    } else {
        fade.fadeOut("slow");
    }
 });
```